# How to get specific array value Cloud Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the value of the second index inside a document of the Firestore database. Currently, I am able to get the entire array but I couldn't get a value by its index.

[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICShq.png)

This is the code I have which returns the entire value of the array .

```
        firebaseFirestore.collection("levels").document("data").get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList) task.getResult().get("images"); 
                    // Here i am getting the entire data from the document
                }
            });
```

Comment: What's wrong with calling `arrayList[2]` there after you get it? I don't think you can read just a single entry from the array through firestore.

Comment: yeah, I can get like that, but I want to get one from Firestore because soon, there will be hundreds of elements in that array.

Comment: I think if getting them all at once is going to be an issue you should change how the database is structured so they are in separate documents rather than an array inside a single document. Firestore can query for specific documents, but not fields within a document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently, I am able to get the entire array.

That's the way Firestore works. All Cloud Firestore listeners fire on the document level. So there is no way you can get only some particular fields in a document. In your case, you cannot get only the "images" array that exists inside that document, or just a value from within that array. It's the entire document or nothing.

> But I couldn't get a value by its index database image.

Since you already got the array, you can get the value that exists at the second index very simply. Knowing that the first index is `0`, the second index would be `1`. So you have to make the following request:

```
ArrayList arrayList = (ArrayList) task.getResult().get("images");
String secondImage = arrayList.get(1);
```

Comment: yeah, I can get like that, but I want to get one from Firestore because soon, there will be hundreds of elements in that array.

Comment: So what? There is no problem with having hundreds of elements in an array. That's usual stuff. But as said before, you cannot get only one element from the array without reading the entire document. That's how Firestore works, right?